# How to Deploy an existing EBS volume to EKS PVC?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I have an existing ebs volume in AWS with data on it. I need to create a PVC in order to use it in my pods.
Following this guide: https://medium.com/pablo-perez/launching-a-pod-with-an-existing-ebs-volume-mounted-in-k8s-7b5506fa7fa3

persistentvolume.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-volume
  labels:
    type: amazonEBS
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 60Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: vol-011111111x
    fsType: ext4
```

```
[$$]>kubectl describe pv
Name:            jenkins-volume
Labels:          type=amazonEBS
Annotations:     <none>
Finalizers:      [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:
Status:          Available
Claim:
Reclaim Policy:  Retain
Access Modes:    RWO
VolumeMode:      Filesystem
Capacity:        60Gi
Node Affinity:   <none>
Message:
Source:
    Type:       AWSElasticBlockStore (a Persistent Disk resource in AWS)
    VolumeID:   vol-011111111x
    FSType:     ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
Events:         <none>
```

persistentVolumeClaim.yaml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pvc-shared4
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  storageClassName: gp2
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 60Gi
```

```
[$$]>kubectl describe pvc jenkins-pvc-shared4 -n jenkins
Name:          jenkins-pvc-shared4
Namespace:     jenkins
StorageClass:  gp2
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----               ----                         -------
  Normal  WaitForFirstConsumer  12s (x2 over 21s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for first consumer to be created before binding
[$$]>kubectl get pvc jenkins-pvc-shared4 -n jenkins
NAME                  STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
jenkins-pvc-shared4   Pending                                      gp2            36s
```

Status is pending (waiting to the consumer to be attached) - but it should already be provisioned.

Answer (score 1):

The "waiting for consumer" message suggests that your StorageClass has its `volumeBindingMode` set to `waitForFirstConsumer`.

The default value for this setting is `Immediate`: as soon as you register a PVC, your volume provisioner would provision a new volume.

The `waitForFirstConsumer` on the other hand would wait for a Pod to request usage for said PVC, before the provisioning a volume.

The messages and behavior you're seeing here sound normal. You may create a Deployment mounting that volume, to confirm provisioning works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The right config should be:

```
[$$]>cat persistentvolume2.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-name
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    fsType: ext4
    volumeID: aws://eu-west-2a/vol-123456-ID
  capacity:
    storage: 60Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: gp2

[$$]>cat persistentVolumeClaim2.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  namespace: new-namespace
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: <app-name>
  name: pvc-name
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 60Gi
  storageClassName: gp2
  volumeName: pv-name
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. I can confirm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try fsType "xfs" instead of ext4

Comment: Definitely not something I would recommend, not knowing what's the base OS, and considering xfsprogs doesn't ship as default in Debian/Ubuntu/...

Answer (score 0):

StorageClass is empty for your PV.
According to your guide, you created storageClass "standard", so add to your PersistentVolume spec

```
storageClassName: standard
```

and also set it in persistentVolumeClaim instead of gp2

Answer (score 0):

I was in a hurry first time I try to answer this because I was solving the same issue on my prod environment, and it seems I broke some rules about how to post here (receiving some "complains" and bad reputation (sigh)).

Although the **awsElasticBlockStore** could have solve the issue, it was deprecated since k8s v1.17. Now it is better to g by the CSI configuration.

In my case I needed to move the volume I had to a different AZ. I deployed the volume from a previous taken snapshot and once available I took note of its VolumeID.

For the **PersistenVolume** I used the followin config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: <PV name>
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce <As I'm using EBS>
  storageClassName: <yout StorageClass if you have one>
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  csi:
    driver: <your csi driver>(in my case ebs.csi.aws.com)
    volumeHandle: <VolumeID>
```

For the **PersistenVolumeClaim** I used the normal approach, nothing new to add:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: <PVC Name>
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce <Rememebr I'm using EBS>
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

I had to delete the previous PV and PVC of my cluster and apply them again. The PV changed status to Bound once the PVC was deployed and the POD was running.

I follow the suggestions and examples on this offical AWS blog: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/persistent-storage-for-kubernetes/